# How to get author of another bot's slash command? discord py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I need to my bot get id of user who used slash command of another (not my) bot: [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IB8W.png)

I have `on_message`, which checks if a bot message was sent on an available channel, but when I use `print(message.author.id)` it doesn't show the author of the command, only the bot id, additionally the message type, it shows me as default, doesn't respond

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if (message.channel.id == 926874863099084830):
        print(message)
```

`<Message id=1027876766963994664 channel=<TextChannel id=926874863099084830 name='┆┆bump' position=7 nsfw=False news=False category_id=880095072794849340> type=<MessageType.default: 0> author=<Member id=302050872383242240 name='DISBOARD' discriminator='2760' bot=True nick=None guild=<Guild id=772531463051804692 name='Imperium RPG' shard_id=None chunked=True member_count=629>> flags=<MessageFlags value=0>>`

Answer (score 0):

[`discord.Message.interaction`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Message.interaction) may be a [`discord.MessageInteraction`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactions/api.html#discord.MessageInteraction) object. Which has a [`user`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactions/api.html#discord.MessageInteraction.user) attribute.

```py
if message.interaction:
    print(message.interaction.user)
```